# ctime change after inotify IN_ATTRIB event

Tags: linux, events, system-calls, inotify

Can someone confirm if the inotify event IN_ATTRIB can arrive before the ctime changes as seen through a stat system call? My testing is showing it is the case (but not always).

Comment: Or even if someone can confirm that the kernel makes ctime/mtime changes available immediately for a stat() after a utimensat() would be great !

Comment: Are you sure that the event IN_ATTRIB you seem to observe before the ctime changes is not caused by a different metadata change?

Comment: It turns out that was exactly it. There was a hard link created to the file in question. Thanks!